# Changing callout sizes in TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I have a large, complex TimelinePlot in which the callout bubbles are too large, as shown here:

[image: Callout bubbles too large]

I'm happy with the font size and layout, but the bounding panes should be reduced (vertically) by a factor of about 0.4 so that all the text is visible.

I checked all the Options on TimeLinePlot but there seem to be none that control the (relative) sizes of the callouts.

How shall I proceed?

---

Here's some working code just to get started.  There are so few entries that there is no problem of overlaps... nevertheless you should be able to use this to (somehow!) shrink the bounding boxes.

```
TimelinePlot[
 {
  
  <|{Entity["Person", "LeonBattistaAlberti::nn464"] -> 
     Interval[{"1404", "1472"}],
    Entity["Person", "AlbertoGiacometti::r8nd9"] -> 
     Interval[{"1901", "1966"}],
    "Mateo di Giovanni" -> Interval[{"1430", "1495"}],
    "Duccio" -> Interval[{"1257", "1318"}],
    Entity["Person", "Titian::fd5g7"] -> Interval[{"1489", "1576"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaoloUccello::sdw3g"] -> 
     Interval[{"1397", "1475"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaoloVeronese::2b848"] -> 
     Interval[{"1528", "1588"}]
    }|>,
  
  <|{Entity["Person", "Adolphe-WilliamBouguereau::fqv94"] -> 
     Interval[{"1825", "1905"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaulCezanne::q7s73"] -> 
     Interval[{"1839", "1906"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaulSignac::22q57"] -> 
     Interval[{"1863", "1935"}],
    Entity["Person", "HenriDeToulouse-Lautrec::77k38"] -> 
     Interval[{"1864", "1901"}]
    }|>}]
```

---

As an addendum:

I found that the below accepted solution works only if the entries are of the text form "John Smith", not an `Entity` (as in many of the above entries).  I have no idea why, but it is a relatively simple matter to convert all the `Entities` into simple text in quotation marks.

Comment: David, could you include example code to play with?

Comment: @MarcoB:  Sorry for the delay, but I've added simple code, as you wisely suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `TimelinePlot` has an undocumented `Method` suboption called `"LabelPadding"`.

```
data = {
  
  <|{Entity["Person", "LeonBattistaAlberti::nn464"] -> 
     Interval[{"1404", "1472"}],
    Entity["Person", "AlbertoGiacometti::r8nd9"] -> 
     Interval[{"1901", "1966"}],
    "Mateo di Giovanni" -> Interval[{"1430", "1495"}],
    "Duccio" -> Interval[{"1257", "1318"}],
    Entity["Person", "Titian::fd5g7"] -> Interval[{"1489", "1576"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaoloUccello::sdw3g"] -> 
     Interval[{"1397", "1475"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaoloVeronese::2b848"] -> 
     Interval[{"1528", "1588"}]
    }|>,
  
  <|{Entity["Person", "Adolphe-WilliamBouguereau::fqv94"] -> 
     Interval[{"1825", "1905"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaulCezanne::q7s73"] -> 
     Interval[{"1839", "1906"}],
    Entity["Person", "PaulSignac::22q57"] -> 
     Interval[{"1863", "1935"}],
    Entity["Person", "HenriDeToulouse-Lautrec::77k38"] -> 
     Interval[{"1864", "1901"}]
    }|>};

TimelinePlot[data]
```

[image]

```
TimelinePlot[data, Method -> {"LabelPadding" -> {{5, 5}, {1, 1}}}]
```

[image]

---

Looks like the available suboptions are

```
{"DefaultPlotStyle", "DynamicOutput", "DateAxisStyle", 
  "TickLengths", "LabelBackground", ChartElementFunction, 
  "LabelHighlightStyle", "LabelPadding"}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for finding the undocumented option.  Clearly your solution provides precisely what I need... ($+1$).  *However*, for some reason your code does not produce the desired results in *Mma* version 11.3.  Are the undocumented options you found available in 11.3?  Or is there some other error I'm making that would prevent your solution from working?

Comment: I don't have 11.3, so I can't test. Does the this provide a workaround? `plot /. (FrameMargins -> w_Integer) :> (FrameMargins -> w {{1, 1}, 0.4 {1, 1}})` If not, does wrapping the call in `CloudEvaluate` work?

Comment: I discovered this with ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions`` in the definition for ``Charting`iTimelinePlot``. Maybe in 11.3 you could check for the appearance of `"LabelPadding"` there?

Comment: `plot /. (FrameMargins -> w_Integer) :> (FrameMargins -> w {{1, 1}, 0.4 {1, 1}})` works (THANKS!), though for some reason in v 11.3 I had to reduce 0.4 significantly (to 0.01).  Good enough, though.  ($\checkmark$)